# Is there a way to, when pressing Enter key, save the data directly on database using slickgrid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

Im trying the slickgrid plugin ! I can red, edit and add data on the db when I press the "save" button. However, I was trying to do the same as excel, where you press the Enter key and it updates on the DB in real time.
I get into the where the key is pressed, but then theres no data at all. It access the function, but then nothing happens. Any help ? Thanks in advance

I've tried with the grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args)  from slickgrid itself but it just dont update. If i just insert one new row and the press "save" , it will add on the db!

```
            $(document).keydown(function () {
                var keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (keyPressed == 13) {
                    console.log("im in");
                    grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                        var idData = jsonResult[key].id + 1;
                        var item = { "id": idData, "t_nome": "", "t_prof": "", "t_data": "", "t_morada": "", "t_percCompleto": "" };
                        $.extend(item, args.item);
                        dataView.addItem(item);
                    });

                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I was expecting that, after the user pressed the Enter key, it updated in real time on the DB but that does not happen.

P.S. Im using the `var idData = jsonResult[key].id + 1` so It can increment on the grid .

Comment: Can you let us know what example page you are using to test this? Also, check you are using the 6pac repo https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples

Comment: Hello @BenMcIntyre ! I started using the example 4 and then "adapted" ! 
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html  From this one, I can insert and update on DB if I click on the save button ( made by me). Now I was trying when the user press enter key, but somehow, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got for solution

```
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            var idData = jsonResult[key].id + 1;
            var item = { "id": idData, "t_nome": "", "t_prof": "", "t_data": "", "t_morada": "", "t_percCompleto": "" };
            $.extend(item, args.item);
            dataView.addItem(item);
            grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function (e) {
                var keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
                if (keyPressed == 13) {
                    alert(item);
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(item);
                    $.post("/SlickTests/editGrid", $("input[name=mydata]").val(myJSON))
                }
            });
        });`
```

But now its giving me a error of deserialize ( cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'!
NEverless, got the answer ! 
Hope it helps someone :)